# Strong convergence of regular operators and convergence of the modulus

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, banach-lattices

Let $E$ be a Banach lattice  and $T_n\in\mathcal{L}^r(E)$ a sequence of regular operators such that $T_n$ converges strongly to $T\in\mathcal{L}^r(E)$. How to prove that $\left|T_n\right|$ converges strongly to $\left|T\right|$, $\left|\cdot\right|$ is the modulus of the operator.
The result holds true for the operator norm convergence.